# If atmas exchange bodies after death, does it mean the population/no. of bodies has to remain constant?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, atma

Quoting Bhagawad Gita 2.22

वासांसि जीर्णानि यथा विहाय
नवानि गृह्णाति नरोऽपराणि।
तथा शरीराणि विहाय जीर्णा
न्यन्यानि संयाति नवानि देही।।2.22।।

"As a person sheds worn-out garments and wears new ones, likewise, at the time of death, the soul casts off its worn-out body and enters a new one."

Does this mean that the total population has to remain constant? Or it continuously decreases as some atmas attain moksha? Is this satisfied by the provision of inter-species transfer of atma considering total biomass remains roughly the same? Is there also a provision of creation of new atma entities?

Comment: There are infinite Atmas so population wouldn't matter. See BG 2.12

Comment: The number of souls remain the same. The amount of materialistic bodies differ however.

Comment: there are an infinite number of jivas. Infinite # of jivas minus an infinite amount of jivas equals an infinite amount of jivas. Infinite is infinite. Each individual organism (including each and every cell in your body) has a jiva.There are billions of bacteria in your body. Billions and billions of jivas in your very body. All jivas are not on the material plane at any given time. There are jivas going through the heavens also.

Answer (score 1):

When anyone dies, it is not necessary for the Atma to get same type of body. Shri Shankaracharya has sermoned - Janthunam durlabamam manushya janmam.

Translated it means "Of all species, getting Human Birth is a rarity". You check your surroundings and the way you live.

To get a comfortable sleep you spray insecticide and can see hundreds of mosquitoes dead. Next night you see same numbers again. Do it whole year and every night you see hundreds dead.

Every non-vegetarian restaurant sells 50-100 chickens daily. You grind millions of wheat grain every week for your family if living in north and millions of rice grain cooked in south.

Thus for one human body you see millions of other birth being sacrificed.

You get rebirth according to the Karma. According to your actions between birth and death, you are reborn as a tree or an insect or a reptile or again as a human.

And remember you may be born as human in Africa, Asia or U.S.A.

Last but not the least to obtain Moksha, you must be born in Bharat varsha and died on its soil.

Comment: I agree with your answer as a whole but seriously doubt the last line. Why only the ones born in Bharat can achieve moksha? Why not others if they deserve it, Do you have any references claiming as such?